# How to customize tailwind typography blockquotes

Tags: tailwind-css

Tailwind typography, In order to add opening and closing quotes, add an `after` and `before` pseudo elements to blockquotes:

```
<blockquote>
    :after
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    :before
</blockquote>
```

I want to customize the style removing just the closing quotes to match this pattern:

[image]

Is it possible customize it from tailwind.config.js or should I override styles with CSS and `!important`?

Comment: Is blockquote any component?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. It is not a TW component. It is rendered by a WordPress normal blockquotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in this issue: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography/issues/66#issuecomment-756834635

You can add following configuration to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
    extend: {
      typography: {
        quoteless: {
          css: {
            'blockquote p:first-of-type::before': { content: 'none' },
            'blockquote p:first-of-type::after': { content: 'none' },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  //...
}
```

and add the class `prose-quoteless` to your prose element afterwards to remove all quotes.